# Why does querying "apache" doesn't work in below document in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple text document which looks like this on fetching it with command:`curl -X GET "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1"`

```
{"_index":"customer","_type":"_doc","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":
{
  "description": "Sun Java Plug-In 1.4 through 1.4.2_02 allows remote attackers to repeatedly access the floppy drive via the createXmlDocument method in the org.apache.crimson.tree.XmlDocument class, which violates the Java security model."
}
}
```

When I make a query on above document with below mentioned query elastic search doesn't give me any matches, I am wondering why?

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "description": "apache"
        }
    }
}
```

and this query is successful if I replace apache with `createXmlDocument` or `org.apache.crimson.tree.XmlDocument`. My initial understanding was org.apache.crimson.tree.XmlDocument will be split in 5 words org, apache, crimson, tree, and XmlDocument but at this point I am thinking maybe the whole org.apache.crimson.tree.XmlDocument is stored as it is by elastic search. If that so, why and how I can get the desired result?

Comment: Can you include your analyzers and mapping? `GET your_index/_settings` and `GET your_index/_mapping`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't define anything, the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will be used.

The Standard Analyzer will create this token:

```
{
  "token" : "org.apache.crimson.tree.xmldocument",
  "start_offset" : 140,
  "end_offset" : 175,
  "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position" : 22
}
```

So your search doesn't find anything. If you use the [Pattern Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) the token `apache` will be created. The default pattern `\W+` (every word) works for you.

You can check this with

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_analyze" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "text": "Sun Java Plug-In 1.4 through 1.4.2_02 allows remote attackers to repeatedly access the floppy drive via the createXmlDocument method in the org.apache.crimson.tree.XmlDocument class, which violates the Java security model.",
  "analyzer": "pattern"
}'
```

Define an explicit mapping for your index like this:

```
PUT customer
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "pattern"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you run the query again, you will get for instance:

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "customer",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "Sun Java Plug-In 1.4 through 1.4.2_02 allows remote attackers to repeatedly access the floppy drive via the createXmlDocument method in the org.apache.crimson.tree.XmlDocument class, which violates the Java security model."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```